# Uiautomator - my try/catch is not working on UiObjectNotFoundException - am I missing something

Tags: android, try-catch, android-uiautomator

Im trying to use a try/catch against a UiObjectNotFoundException, but code in my catch block is never executed, even though the try block catches the exception.  Am I missing something...are we unable to continue if a UiObjectNotFoundException is thrown?  If so, is there any technique to continue if a UiObjectNotFoundException is thrown?

```
        UiScrollable scrollableListResults = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()
                .resourceId("com.example:id/listView")
                .className(android.widget.ListView.class.getName()));

        UiObject obj;
        try {
            System.out.println("Trying textView");
            obj = scrollableListResults.getChild(new UiSelector()
                    .resourceId("com.example:id/textView")
                    .textContains("Text"));
        } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException onfe) {
            System.out.println("Trying textViewLabel");
            obj = scrollableListResults.getChild(new UiSelector()
                    .resourceId("com.example:id/textViewLabel")
                    .textContains("Text"));
            }
```

Comment: Can you post the exact output?

Comment: Which object is not being found? Don't forget your try catch does not involve the getChild under your catch. It may be this one that's not being caught.

Comment: Btw, the try-catch system is exactly the same as in any other technology. If an exception occurs it goes to catch (if it's being caught ofc) and the code continues after it.

Comment: Try with a NullPointerException (I have both in my code and I'm not sure why I did it back then lol)

Answer (score -1):

if you want to continue your code even if any exception is thrown, you can use the "finally" block. If want to know how to handle exceptions in android, read this link.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Hope that can help you